# Sum Integers written into a String

Tags: java, string, integer

I used

```
int num = Integer.parseInt(str)
```

to written integer values into a string.I need a function that reads these values
from given string and calculates their sum.

Example: input - "43 68 9 23 318" 
output - 461

Comment: You need to split this string in substrings using the space as separator.  Then, iterate on each substring and convert to a integer with Integer.parseInt(str).

Comment: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/ma14-java-se-8-streams-2177646.html

Answer (score 9):

```
String str = "43 68 9 23 318";
int num = Integer.parseInt(str)
```

What you are doing is, trying to parse the complete input string at once, that will throw the `NumberFormatException`. You need to split it first and then perform the sum on each returned `String`.

---

Split the input string by `whitespace` then parse each number and perform the sum.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  String input = "43 68 9 23 318";
  String numbers[] = input.split("\\s+");   // Split the input string.
  int sum = 0;
  for (String number : numbers) {  // loop through all the number in the string array
    Integer n = Integer.parseInt(number);  // parse each number
    sum += n;     // sum the numbers
  }
  System.out.println(sum);  // print the result.
}
```

Answer (score 6):

In Java 8, using streams

```
String input = "43 68 9 23 318";
String numbers[] = input.split("\\s+");
int[] nums = Arrays.stream(numbers.substring(1, numbers.length()-1).split(","))
    .map(String::trim).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray();
int sum = IntStream.of(nums).sum();
System.out.println("The sum is " + sum);
```

Answer (score 3):

Another Java 8 way:

```
public void test() {
    String str = "43 68 9 23 318";
    int sum = Pattern.compile(" ")
            .splitAsStream(str)
            .mapToInt(Integer::parseInt)
            .sum();
    System.out.println("sum:" + sum);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try following with [java-8](/questions/tagged/java-8). Here we first split the `String` to get `String[]` with number `String` (*i.e* `["43", "68", "9", "23", "318"]`) and then with the help of `Arrays.stream` we can *map* all those `Strings` to `Integer` and we will have `IntStream` and from that we can get `sum` of all streamed `Integer` values.

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String input = "43 68 9 23 318";
        int sum = Arrays.stream(input.trim().split("\\s+"))
                        .mapToInt(Integer::parseInt)
                        .sum();
        System.out.println(sum);
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
461
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to go to the hassle of splitting it you can do it in-place:

```
public void test() {
    String str = "43 68 9 23 318";
    int sum = 0;
    int value = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        char ch = str.charAt(i);
        switch (ch) {
            case '0':
            case '1':
            case '2':
            case '3':
            case '4':
            case '5':
            case '6':
            case '7':
            case '8':
            case '9':
                value = value * 10 + (ch - '0');
                break;
            default:
                sum += value;
                value = 0;
                break;

        }

    }
    // Remember the last number.
    sum += value;
    value = 0;
    System.out.println("sum:" + sum);
}
```

Comment: @redFIVE - I'd be willing to bet it is significantly faster than most of the others though.

Answer (score 1):

**This is the needed Working copy with function**

```
    public class Main {
            /*This function is static because we called it from static main*/
        public static int returnSum(String str)
        {
            String []numbStr = str.split(" ");
            int sum = 0;

            for(String temp:numbStr)
            {
                 sum += Integer.parseInt(temp);
            }

            return sum;
        }

        public static void main(String... args)
        {
            String str = "43 68 9 23 318";
                    /*Note that we can call only static functions from main when directly calls*/ 
            int result =  returnSum(str);

            System.out.println(result);

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Java 8 Streams in one line

```
Arrays.stream(text.split(" ")).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).sum();
```

Answer (score 0):

This works not only for the strings that contains numbers separated by spaces but also for the strings containing characters others than numbers like "abc10jh20"-->30

```
 import java.util.Arrays.*;
    public class HelloWorld{
        //this code works also if the string contains alphabets not just spaces
    static int count,sum;
         public static void main(String []args){
             String str="123 10 7";//getting input in form of string
             int length=str.length();
             for(int i=0;i<=length-1;i=i+count+1)
             {
                 count=0;
                 if(Character.isDigit(str.charAt(i)))
                 {
                     for(int j=i;j<=length-1;j++)
                     {
                         if(Character.isDigit(str.charAt(j)))
                         {
                             count++;//to find the length of the number

                         }
                         else{
                             break;
                         }

                     }
                     String str2=str.substring(i,i+count);//selecting the substring
                     System.out.println("the parsing string "+str2);//displays strings getting parsed
                     int inc=count+1;

                      sum=sum+Integer.parseInt(str2);//finding sum

                 }

             }
             System.out.println("the sum is "+sum);
         }
    }
```